# Openshift: How many pods my springboot app need?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod, traffic

I´ve a springboot aplication running on Openshift. I've not set any quota limits. How can I get how many pods replica do I need? It depend of the amount of traffic only?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, OpenShift(Kubernetes) controller determines how many pods can be scheduled on the worker nodes across the cluster through configured requests resources on new pods. But if you have not configured any requests resources on the new pods, then theoretically you can schedule the pod replicas until all worker node allow to run the pod container processes well. It means Kubernetes can not determine how many pod can be scheduled appropriately. So you should configure resources requests(cpu and memory) for best performance and using resources efficiently through the performance test on your application.

Comment: Agreed, especially on the performance testing. Worth noting that it is best practice to always set "requests" and "limits". Using the HorizontalPodAutoscaler can also help to automatically scale as a result of resources used.